# Graphs: Nodes with max degree of 4, each node tries to connect to 4 nearest nodes - how many connections lost?

Tags: neural-network, geospatial, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am currently looking into spatially embedded networks, and am having trouble finding an answer for the following. Lets say I have a network with N nodes. Each of these nodes are located in space, and have 4 ports from which a connection can be made (meaning each node has a maximum degree of 4). Each node tries to connect with its 4 closest neighbors. (Links are bidirectional)

The following problem occurs:

[image]

As connections are added, certain nodes will reach their maximum degree. Another node may have this node as one of its closest neighbors, but can't connect to it because the other node cannot accept anymore connections. These 'attempts' are highlighted in red.

Is there any way to generalize this problem and determine how many connections are possible within the graph? How does the ordering in which connections are made affect the results?

Comment: Could be an interesting (and possibly difficult) problem. But it's not entirely clear what "kind" of answer you expect. From a first short (!) glance, I'd say that the *number* of connections is fixed: For each red edge that you could add, you'd have to remove exactly one other edge. The order of insertion should not be relevant. The total number of edges in the graph will then just be `sumOfAllDegrees/2`. It would be maximal here for a 4-regular graph (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph ). But I assume that your considerations involve some "weighting", based on the distance...?

Answer (score 0):

The order of connections are made is irrelevant. Suppose, the connections are established at once without maximal node degree restriction. After that, some of the nodes can have more connections than is allowed. Therefore, you have to remove some of the newly added connections to satisfy the restriction. Nevertheless, how many connections have to be removed is defined, though, which connections is not.

If you have a criterion which evaluates your network you can use dynamic programming approach to remove invalid connections in a newly established network to maximize value of the network.